# OpenGL ES 1.1 Alpha Blending sorting on a single mesh

Tags: ios, sorting, opengl-es

I am working on a Iphone game that uses OpenGL ES 1.1 for rendering and we having some issues getting alpha sorting to work correctly on an big mesh. The mesh in questions is of a stadium and the alpha parts are the crowd in the stadium. The problem is that when using Alpha Blending on the crowd we get some sorting issues that result in the user not being able to differentiate the front of the crowd from the back of the crowd. In most cases the crowd just shows up as a jumbled mess and no one can really tell who should be where.

Normally to fix an issue like this I would simply separate the stadium and the crowd from one another and then separate each crowd section(Each Crowd is on its own plane) so that we could better sort them. But we need to keep the draw count to under 100 objects so this is not something that we can do.

Another idea that I had was to try and do some kind of crazy sorting by taking all the vertices and then trying to sort them via clockwise rotation. IE, take vers 0 to 10 and draw them first and then take verts 11 to 20 and then draw then next and so on and so forth until the whole crowd is drawn but I have no idea how to even begin doing this or of this is even possible to do.

If that is not possible I was thinking that I could have an artist cut up the crowd meshes so that it fits the profile of the people that are displayed on it better so that we are displaying less alpha thus leaving us with less overdraw and possibly better sorting. But I am not sure if adding more vertes will cause any performance issues as I do not have a lot of experience with the Iphone.

If any one has any ideas or links to any article that might help me better understand this issue that would be very helpful and I would like to thank you now for any help that you might provide.

Comment: It's not at all clear from your description how you're currently drawing things. For something like a crowd, couldn't you draw them in back to front order without depth testing?

Comment: We are currently drawing everything in one mesh, the crowd and the stadium. Like I said before I did suggest cutting the crowd out of the stadium but was told that this is not possible due restrictions. Is it possible to do this any other way or is separating the crowd form the stadium the best way to go about this.

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark. I'd like to know how that works out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your structure has an alpha it has to be sorted.  If not it doesn't.

Here's my idea... Have them split out the stadium and the crowd. You said each crowd is a plane.. so have each crowd be a separate item - but have them force each crowd plane to be the same number of indices.. 6 or 2 sets whatever each one is.

Hopefully the stadium doesn't have any alpha and only the crowd does.  In that case arrange the data so that it's stored in an array like this: stadium, then crowd 1 plane, crowd 2 plane, etc.  Then load the vertices for each crowd plane in a another bunch of arrays.

Hopefully also you're triangles and not triangle strips.  So then you have vertices and indices.  The only structure you'll have to change in that case is the order of the planes, which is just 6 indices per plane.. (or however many it is).

Sort the planes for the crowds based on distance from the camera.  Then copy the data from the crowd plane arrays to over write the indices data for those planes.. and then draw the whole batch as one object.  You probably won't be able to use VBOs but you can do it as one object.

Remember that just because you're drawing it as one object doesn't mean it has to be delivered to you as one object.